# PyGtk CellRendererProgress start/end positions

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Is there any way to fill a gtk.CellRendererProgress indicating the start
and end positions? Not just the end.

As an example of what I would need to do is, instead of this:

```
|##############################----------| (from 0% to 80%)
```

I need to do this:

```
|--------######################----------| (from 25% to 80%)
```

It's like a pulsing ProgressBar but without moving and I need to specify at wich percentage the bar starts and ends.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. But you can write a custom cell renderer that does that, based on the code for `CellRendererProgress`.